# How do I speed up the rate at which DynamoDB streams fire INSERT events?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a setup where every time an item is inserted in my table, I call a Lambda function. I'm trying to cut huge images in 256x256 tiles, it's a one time job but I need a few million lambda calls.

The system works, but very slowly, around 30 invocations/sec. I can see the iterator age increasing in the lambda monitor.

- The lambda concurrency limit is 1000
- The DynamoDB is using provisioned capacity, auto-scaling, 1k reads/writes max

Where is the bottleneck coming from?

Comment: How many concurrent lambda invocations do you get?

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan Around 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to ensure is that you have retries enabled and not using the default -1 value which can cause your stream shard to block.

Then you can increase the performance doing a mixture of the following:

1. Increase your Lambda memory
2. Increase the parallelization factor of the Lambda (up to 10X)
3. Pre-warm your DynamoDB table to give you more shards
4. Reduce BatchSize
5. Refine your Lambda logic to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will definitely keep those tips in mind for the future. For the time being I decided to skip the dynamodb step and call lambda functions directly from other lambdas. I don't see async events being dropped in the monitoring tab, it seems to be working fine with around 100k invocations in 5 mins.